Como computadores diferenciam tipos de dados
Essa é uma dúvida que sempre tive, mas não encontrei conteúdo o suficiente para responde-la.
Pelo que eu pesquisei, computadores interpretam código binário com a ausência ou presença de corrente elétrica, mas esses bits podem ser caracteres (unicode), cores (rgb), números, comandos etc... Mas se é tudo 0 e 1 como o processador sabe diferenciar isso tudo?
OBS: A pergunta é apenas uma curiosidade minha...

Os comentários foram movidos para o chat.
